# HTML/JS - text-shadow for inputs?

Tags: forms, html, input, submit, css

Is it even possible to force text-shadow on elements like:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

?

Of course text-shadow doesn't work in any browser when it comes to inputs... Will it be working in near future?

I can't edit the HTML, only JS & CSS tricks allowed. I want a solution that will work in all modern browsers, don't care about IE7 and older.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/tUDLM/

Answer (score 1):

I think it works on modern browsers that support these CSS properties.

```
    #submit {
padding: 1em 2em;
font-size: 1.4em;
border: 0;
color: #fff;
background-color: #999;
-moz-text-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #fff000;
-webkit-text-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #fff000;
text-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #fff000;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #000;
}​
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/L2SY5/2/
I hope this helps. Please notice that i have used some vendor prefix to ensure wider support. Just in case, for cross browser solution you can use CSS PIE, though i have heard of some performance issues. http://www.css3pie.com/